# StringUtil defaultIfBlank disappearing after adding kube java client

Tags: java, maven

I'm adding the following dependencies to my maven project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>       
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-java-extended</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, after adding this, StringUtils.defaultsIfBlank disappears and my code fails to compile. I've tried adding the following exclusions to these dependencies:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

I found that the StringUtils class that goes into the classpath is coming from io.sundr:sundr-codegen:0.22.0 which is a dependency from Kube and is packed as an uber jar. this seems odd, how do I make the StringUtils in my direct dependency to take precendence?

Comment: How are you importing `StringUtil`?

Comment: import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

Answer (score 0):

You can see which version of `commons-lang` is being pulled in by using the [`dependency:tree` goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html).  It sounds like perhaps one of these dependencies you list above is transitively bringing in a different version of `commons-lang` than you are implicitly requiring.

Comment: before adding io.kubernetes it works fine.After adding it, the issue occurs. Which leads me to believe there is something wrong with the exclusion code shown.

Comment: version being pulled is the same as the direct dependency, it's not even pulling the one from io.kube and still the method is disappearing.

Maven dependency management states that the “nearest” definition wins. If you have a direct dependency on a library, nothing should be able to override its version. but somehow StringUtils is not getting the right thing

Comment: It is of course hard to diagnose these issues without your `pom.xml`. That said, you can see that at least `client-java` depends on commons-lang3 version 3.1.1: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/1c0f0c879da933046d0587c0bee4a9139f05bf44/pom.xml#L90-L94 I don't know what version you are expecting, of course. Also, regarding exclusions, you have to apply them for every dependency that might transitively pull in the offending dependency. So: exclude, then `dependency:tree`, then add more exclusions, repeat…. Finally, are you direct-depending on `commons-lang3` yourself? What version?

Comment: I do have direct dependencies to both commons-lang and common-lang3, lang3 doesn't have the problem, it's just lang, ex: if I replace all  org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils by org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils, then it works, the StringUtils been replace is the one coming from lang only. 

I thought excluding like in the snippet mentioned on the question should exclude it from everything below client-java and client-java-extended. is that not the case?

Comment: I found that the StringUtils class that goes into the classpath is coming from io.sundr:sundr-codegen:0.22.0 which is a dependency from Kube. How can I stop that from happening?

Comment: I recommend you do this: add `<exclusions>`, then do `mvn depencency:tree`.  You'll (probably) see that your artifact has "reappeared" because now there is a different transitive dependency path to it (through some other artifact).  Add exclusions to _that_ artifact, run `mvn dependency:tree`, and so on.  You'll rapidly learn how this works.  Even better: don't use commons-lang and don't use commons-lang3 if at all humanly possible!

Comment: Hi Laird, thanks for replying, adding the exclusion is not excluding it, because it's coming from a direct dependency, issue here is that sundr-codegen is packed as uber jar with a different version. since it's packed that way, exclusion doesn't work. Do you have any other recommendation?

Comment: I do not.  IMHO that's a problem with that library's packaging strategy and you have very few solutions available to you.  Perhaps you can get away with depending on `sundr-core` instead?